# Links above page alignment

Tags: css, hyperlink, position, alignment

Does anyone know how to get your links to sit on top of your background image and page contents rather than inline next to your page.

Example:     Home  About  Contact etc.
under that:  The rest of the page. The background and the page contents.

Right now as it stands my links are in line to the left side of the page and right beside it is the background and page contents.

How do i fix that?

Comment: Please show us basic structure and styling so far. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

i assume you could use "display: inline-block" to keep the links in the navbar on the same line, and then use vertical-align or "valign:top" to align the links to the top of the page.